# filter angular accordion filter simple array with value pass in input

Tags: angular, typescript

HI i want filter my array accordion where value of question with enter value pass in this.input,i try with method like filter

```
  this.accordionItems = [
  
   {
      "topic":"polizze",
      "question":"Le mie polizze sono attive?",
      "answer":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing… qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
   },
   {
      "topic":"polizze",
      "question":"Come si cambia il beneficiario?",
      "answer":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing… qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
   },
   {
      "topic":"sinistri",
      "question":"Come annullo un appuntamento?",
      "answer":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing… qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
   }
]

 this.input = 'polizze';
    if (this.accordionItems) {
      this.accordionItems = this.accordionItems.filter(request =>
        request.question.toLowerCase() === this.input.toLowerCase());
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are comparing filter incorrectly. Filter will give items matching with input value.

Try below that will filter out all items with topic = polizze

```
this.accordionItems = this.accordionItems.filter(request =>
    request.topic.toLowerCase() == this.input.toLowerCase());
```